# Get Custom Module details from Azure Automation

Tags: azure, powershell, api, powershell-3.0, azure-automation

I have created custom module and uploaded it in Azure Automation module section. Now when I try to run the command to fetch the list of modules, it is not showing over there. I have used PowerShell command and REST API also but it is giving me value of Default modules only. Is there any way I can get the details of custom module?

I have tried below 2 ways-

1. Powershell - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.automation/get-azautomationmodule?view=azps-7.0.0
2. API

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the one of workaround that i was able to fetch the custom module that i have added to Azure Automation using `Powershell`

- Added [Microsoft teams](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/MicrosoftTeams/3.0.0) custom module to my Azure Automation .

Run the following `cmd` to get all the modules `default` and `custom`

```
Get-AzAutomationModule -AutomationAccountName "<name>" -ResourceGroupName "<name>"
```

[image]

To Fetch the list of custom modules run the below `cmd`

```
Get-AzAutomationModule -AutomationAccountName "<name>" -Name "MicrosoftTeams" -ResourceGroupName "<name>"
```

[image]

Also can able to see it from azure portal itself. Also make sure that you have added the custom module with some functionality .